# Unload modules/styles dynamically in webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have to import certain list of styles dynamically based on landing page and all the other pages.
but when navigating from landing page to another page, I have to unload bootstrap style, as bootstrap conflict with myStyle:

```
// if we are in landing page then load bootstrap otherwise load myStyle
 if (props.location.pathname === '/') {
    import(`./assets/css/bootstrap.css`);
  } else {
    import(`./assets/css/myStyle.css`);
  }
```

this is what I have tried so far but it doesn't do anything.(my theme collapse because of conflicting styles)
what I want is a way to dynamically unload a style completely in a page.

```
 if (props.location.pathname === '/') {
    delete require.cache[require.resolve('./assets/css/myStyle.css')];
    import(`./assets/css/bootstrap.css`);
  } else {
    delete require.cache[require.resolve('./assets/css/bootstrap.css')];
    import(`./assets/css/myStyle.css`);
  }
```

does Webpack support such a scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Please let me take you a step back just to clarify what webpack is all about. It creates bundles according to defined entrypoints. Using import/require declarations it collects all the files that are necessary to create such bundles (using appropriate loaders).

Now, let me go back to your question. You are saying that under some conditions depending on URL address you need or need not bootstrap.

Assuming that you are not using SPA, you can load bootstrap in `<script>` tag independently on the page that you need (landing) and on others - don't. Assuming that you are creating SPA - I don't even know how to accomplish what you are looking for. Please remember that at the end of a day, after all what webpack does, we are given static html + css + js files.

Moreover, I don't quite get how the unloading would even look like, I feel that you may think about `webpack-dev-server` and HMR stuff which obviously should not be used on production.

Comment: obviously Webpack supports [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-1). are you aware of that? if this is true, then, there must be something to unload it...

Comment: Ok, that's a point. I didn't express myself clear. 
I meant I cannot imagine how it would potentially work assuming one-run done by webpack during app build on CI. If you are talking about dynamic load/unload the only think I can imagine is HMR (along with webpack-dev-server during development) which does not fit in this case since the prod should not use it at all.

Comment: I think this answer really misses the point. This has nothing to do with HMR. This has to do with dynamic module loading, which webpack has. That is HOW code splitting is designed to work in react. The question of how to unload a dynamically loaded module is a good question, especially when it comes to other types of modules like CSS in JS, and so on.